# How to display Jquerymobile app differently to mobile and tablet

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

Im building an app with Jquery mobile and Phonegap and my employer wishes that the app displays content differently on an tablet and on an Iphone, especially he wants the app to display an certain form on an Iphone with input field stacked on top of each other and spread out on an tablet since it has more space on the sides. On the tablet it should also be fixed horisontally. Does anyone know some resources to dig deeper into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you heard of [Responsive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)? This will make use of css [media queries](http://mediaqueri.es/) to display the contents based on the screen size of the device.

jQuery Mobile has some [built in support for responsive design](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/intro/rwd.php), but sky is your limit for your innovative designs.

[Check this simple tutorial too.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/library/mo-jquery-responsive-design/)